# MySQL: Group by date proximity?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I wrote this query, it does almost what I want:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt,
   lat,
   lon,
   elev, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(usaf,'-',wban))
   FROM `ISH-HISTORY_HASPOS` 
   GROUP BY  lat,lon,elev 
 ) AS x WHERE cnt >=1;
```

output:

```
+-----+--------+----------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
| cnt | lat    | lon      | elev   | GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(usaf,'-',wban))                              |
+-----+--------+----------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
|   4 | 30.478 |  -87.187 | 36     | 722220-13899,722221-13899,722223-13899,999999-13899              |
|   4 | 36.134 |  -80.222 | 295.7  | 723190-93807,723191-93807,723193-93807,999999-93807              |
|   5 | 37.087 |  -84.077 | 369.1  | 723290-03849,723291-03849,723293-03849,724243-03849,999999-03849 |
|   5 | 38.417 | -113.017 | 1534.1 | 745200-23176,745201-23176,999999-23176,724757-23176,724797-23176 |
|   4 | 40.217 |  -76.851 | 105.8  | 999999-14751,725110-14751,725111-14751,725118-14751              |
+-----+--------+----------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

This returns a concatenated list of stations that are located at identical coordinates. However, I am only interested in concatenating stations with adjoining date ranges. The table that I select from (ISH-HISTORY_HASPOS) has two datetime columns : 'begin' and 'end'. I need the values for these two columns to be within 3 days of each other to satisfy the GROUP_CONCAT  conditions.

**Edit:** In order for a station to be included in the final result's GROUP_CONCAT it must satisfy the following conditions:

1. It must be co-located with another station in the list (group by
   lat,lon,elev)
2. Its `end` time must be within 3 days of another station's `begin` time OR its `begin` time must be within 3 days of another station's
   `end` time. When I say "another station", I am referring to stations
   that are co-located (meet the conditions for #1).

I figure that I will have to use a subquery but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Some help would be greatly appreciated! Either a query or a stored procedure would be great but a php solution would also be acceptable.

Here is a dump of the table that I am querying:[sql dump](http://www.furlender.com/ISH-HISTORY_HASPOS.sql)

The results should look the same as my example, but non-adjoining items (date-wise) should not be there.

Comment: Example data and required results would help make this clearer.

Comment: Say row 1 is today, row 2 is 3 days ago, and row 3 is six days ago. How do these get grouped? 1 and 3 are within 3 days of 2, but 6 days from each other.

Comment: @llion great question - i just realized I hadnt explained that. In your example all of those would be included. A row just has to be 3 days away from ANY other row to be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be using a subquery to compute the list of station within 3 days of each other and adding this subquery as a where clause to the main query.
The subquery consists of a cartesian product to list all possible station couples with a first condition to get just the first half of the resulting matrix and two conditions to specify the time constraints. As to these latter conditions I just guessed them, I don't really know the `begin` and `end` fields unit of measure.
The resulting query could be this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS
       cnt,
       lat,
       lon,
       elev,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(usaf, '-', wban))  
    FROM ISH-HISTORY_HASPOS  
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT t1.id  
        FROM ISH-HISTORY_HASPOS t1  
        INNER JOIN ISH-HISTORY_HASPOS t2
           ON t1.lon = t2.lon
           AND t1.lat = t2.lat
           AND t1.elev = t2.elev  
        WHERE t1.id < t2.id
            AND abs(t1.begin - t2.end) < 259200
            AND abs(t1.end - t2.begin) < 259200  
        UNION  
        SELECT DISTINCT t2.id  
        FROM ISH-HISTORY_HASPOS t1  
        INNER JOIN ISH-HISTORY_HASPOS t2
            ON t1.lon = t2.lon
            AND t1.lat = t2.lat
            AND t1.elev = t2.elev  
        WHERE t1.id < t2.id
            AND abs(t1.begin - t2.end) < 259200
            AND abs(t1.end - t2.begin) < 259200
    )
    GROUP BY lat, lon, elev   
) AS x WHERE cnt >= 1;
```

Comment: Excellent, I believe you got it! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

I only have access and knowledge of SQL Server so I can't get your data to work and I don't know if MySQL has the equivalent functionality but here is a verbal description of what you need to do.

You need a recursive statement (WITH CTE in SQL Server) to join the table to itself on lat, lon, elev and begin BETWEEN end -3 AND end +3. You will need to be careful not to get caught in an infinite loop - I suggest building a comma seperated list of the IDs you have visited and checking this as you go. Its painful but keep this list in ID order becuase it is what you will need to group on at the end. You also need to keep track of your depth and the original id.

Something like ...

```
WITH cte(id, idlist, lat, lon, elev, starts, ends)
AS (
SELECT id, CAST(id AS varchar), lat, lon, elev, starts, ends
FROM `ISH-HISTORY_HASPOS`
UNION ALL
SELECT i.id, FunctionToManagetheList(i.idlist, cte.id), lat, lon, elev, starts, ends
FROM `ISH-HISTORY_HASPOS` i
     INNER JOIN
     cte ON i.lat=cte.lat AND 
            i.lon=cte.lon AND 
            i.elev=cte.elev AND
            NOT FunctionToCheckIfTheIDisintheLitst(i.id, cte.idlist)
)
SELECT stuffyouneed
FROM   `ISH-HISTORY_HASPOS` i
       INNER JOIN
       (SELECT id, MAX(depth) AS MaxDepth
       FROM    cte 
       GROUP BY id) cte1 ON i.id=cte.id
       INNER JOIN
       cte cte2 ON cte1.id=cte2.id AND cte1.MaxDepth=cte2.Depth
GROUP BY cte.idlist
```